# "Connection reset by peer" when benchmarking a simple Rust HTTP server with ab

Tags: multithreading, http, server, rust, apachebench

I'm trying to write an extremely simple concurrent server in Rust to play with the language's concurrency primitives and its threading model.  Here's my code:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::Result;
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream, Shutdown};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) -> Result<()> {
    try!(stream.write(b"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: 5\r\n\r\nPong!\r\n"));
    // try!(stream.shutdown(Shutdown::Both));

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:1337").unwrap();
    // let count = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                // let count = count.clone();
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    let _ = handle_client(stream);

                    // let mut count = count.lock().unwrap();
                    // *count += 1;
                    // println!("{:?}", *count);
                });
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error: {}", e);
            }
        }
    }

    drop(listener);
}
```

When I run `ab -c 100 -n 100 http://127.0.0.1:1337/` with the program running as listed above, I get `apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)` almost immediately.  Why?

When I add `try!(stream.shutdown(Shutdown::Both));` (commented out near the top, above) I no longer get the `apr_socket_recv` error like before, but apachebench gives me results that say 199 failed requests due to exceptions.  Why?  What am I doing wrong?

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.008 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        199
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 0, Exceptions: 199)
Total transferred:      500 bytes
```

Comment: BTW, your content length is not 5, it's 7 (you missed last \r\n). But it is unlikely that this is the reason of the error, I think...

Comment: can you try running it in verbose mode (adding the `-v` flag to the command line)? It's curious that 2/3 of the requests fail... If all of them failed I'd have understood...

Comment: I'd recommend against `use std::io::Result` as that will shadow the "normal" `Result` type. I'd suggest `use std::io` and `io::Result` instead. Also, it's very rare to need to use `drop` explicitly. Values will be automatically dropped at the end of the scope they are defined in.

Comment: You should also create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) when asking a question. For example, [this version](http://is.gd/uhBwAY) uses **no threading** but has the same problem when run with `ab -c 1 -n 5000`.

Comment: Additionally, cURL occasionally reports the same "connection reset" error, so it's nothing specific to apachebench.

Comment: [This Rust bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18847) might potentially be of interest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are not fully reading the data sent *from the client*, so the client never has a chance to transition to reading the response. When it tries to write more data, it notices the socket has been closed and fails.

I've augmented your example to read all the HTTP headers before replying, ignoring any request body. I'm punting on pretty error handling and just panicking if there are errors:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::thread;

fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    // Read all the headers
    for header in BufReader::new(&mut stream).lines() {
        let header = header.unwrap();
        if header == "\r" { break }
    }

    // Write our response
    stream.write_all(b"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n").unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();
        thread::spawn(|| {
            handle_client(stream);
        });
    }
}
```

This works with `ab -c 50 -n 5000 http://127.0.0.1:8080/`:

```
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 500 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 1500 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 2500 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 3500 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 4500 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Finished 5000 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        0 bytes

Concurrency Level:      50
Time taken for tests:   1.293 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      95000 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    3868.22 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       12.926 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.259 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          71.77 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        1    6   1.7      6      14
Processing:     1    6   1.7      6      14
Waiting:        1    6   1.7      6      14
Total:          5   13   2.6     12      23

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     12
  66%     13
  75%     13
  80%     14
  90%     17
  95%     19
  98%     21
  99%     22
 100%     23 (longest request)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of TcpStream](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html) states that

> The socket will be closed when the value is dropped.

Since your function ends without properly shutting down the TCP-stream but simply by closing the socket, you get the `Connection reset by peer` error. A full TCP-shutdown requires multiple messages to be sent in both directions. This obviously can't happen anymore since the socket was closed.

I don't have an answer for your second question. Also, on stackoverflow you should only ask one question per question.

Comment: This seems awfully suspicious. It would be a pretty bad design for the `Drop` implementation to not close the TCP connection in the proper way.

Comment: If it wouldn't do that it might take arbitrarily long for the `Drop::drop` call to finish. Neither behavior is perfect, but this way it's deterministic.

Comment: So how is one supposed to properly close the socket, respecting TCP?

Comment: just as shown in the question: by calling [shutdown](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.shutdown)

Comment: Adding `shutdown` and `flush` did not fix the error for me. I added another answer.

Comment: did not fix the `Connection reset by peer` error or the 2/3 failure chance?

Comment: Did not fix the `connection reset by peer`. I am on OS X, what are you on? Can you post the code you used that worked with apachebench?