# Basic `listenOn` HTTP server "Recv failure: Connection reset by peer"

Tags: http, haskell

While diving into Haskell's `Network` library, I'm making a very simple HTTP server based on info from [this link](https://wiki.haskell.org/Simple_Servers).

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Network
import System.IO

main = withSocketsDo $ listenOn (PortNumber 8080) >>= loop

loop :: Socket -> IO ()
loop sock = do
  (h,_,_) <- accept sock
  forkIO $ handleRequest h
  loop sock

handleRequest :: Handle -> IO ()
handleRequest h = do
  hPutStr h $ httpRequest "Pong!\n"
  hFlush h
  hClose h

httpRequest :: String -> String
httpRequest body = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
  ++ "Content-Length: " ++ (show.length) body ++ "\r\n"
  ++ "\r\n" ++ body ++ "\r\n"
```

However, even though I manage to get some response, the handles seems to be closed unexpectedly soon (sometimes?) as curl tells me:

```
$ curl localhost:8080
Pong!
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

*NB: Sometimes I don't even get the message (`Pong!`) or just a part of it. Sometimes, it works... but if I run 100 `curl`s in a row I eventually get some connection resets.*

Why is the connection reset? I tried with and without `forkIO` without success. Have I missed some essential about IO streams in Haskell? Thanks!

*OS: recent Ubuntu ; GHC: 7.8.4*

**--- Edit: ---**

jozefg identified that the problem came from draining the request's contents! However I'd like to send this content back to the client and it hangs while using the following code:

```
handleRequest :: Handle -> IO ()
handleRequest h = do
  contents <- getHandleContents h
  hPutStr h $ httpRequest contents
  hFlush h
  hClose h

getHandleContents :: Handle -> IO String
getHandleContents h = do
  iseof <- hIsEOF h
  if iseof
    then return []
    else do
      newLine <- hGetLine h
      nextLines <- getHandleContents h
      return $ newLine ++ '\n' : nextLines
```

Moreover I had no success draining the whole contents using `hGetContents`. Any idea why?

Comment: To answer my additional question in the edit: I can't try to read until EOF because it's the server's role to close the connection (thus, we would only wait for nothing). Instead, if the client specifies the `Content-Length` header, we would read the number of bytes specified to get the body. This also explains why `hGetContents` hung the program.

Comment: You are closing the handle before everything is written. When you close the handle, you also close the connection. Removing `hClose h` makes it work 100% of the time on my machine. The solution *in practice* is to use a higher level http server library and have it worry about these sorts of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems to be that you are not fully reading the data the client sends upon making a get-request as described in this [answer for Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360721/connection-reset-by-peer-when-benchmarking-a-simple-rust-http-server-with-ab?rq=1). The solution proposed there is basically to write a small loop which drains the header from the handle before you respond. The Haskell version is

```
drainHeaders :: Handle -> IO ()
drainHeaders h = do
  line <- hGetLine h
  if line == "\r" then return () else drainHeaders h
```

so then your code may be written

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception (bracket)
import Control.Monad
import Network
import System.IO

main = withSocketsDo $
  bracket (listenOn (PortNumber 8080)) sClose loop

loop :: Socket -> IO ()
loop sock = do
  (handle, _host, _port) <- accept sock
  -- Handle is automatically closed now even in the face of async exns
  forkFinally (handleRequest handle) (const $ hClose handle)
  loop sock

drainHeaders :: Handle -> IO ()
drainHeaders h = do
  line <- hGetLine h -- Strips off a trailing \n
  if line == "\r" then return () else drainHeaders h

handleRequest :: Handle -> IO ()
handleRequest h = do
  drainHeaders h
  hPutStr h $ httpRequest "Pong!\n"
  hFlush h

httpRequest :: String -> String
httpRequest body =
  mconcat [ "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: "
          , (show . length) body
          , "\r\n\r\n"
          , body
          , "\r\n" ]
```

I also took the liberty of tweaking the code to make it a bit more exception safe by using `forkFinally` and `bracket` to handle closing things in the face of exceptions: I doubt it's 100% perfect but it's now a little bit cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for these nice improvements! So `drainHeaders` does the job and that's great news for me :) but my initial purpose actually was to send the request's content back to the client. I'll paste in the question the code I used to read the handle. The problem is I don't manage to finish reading the handle and everything is printed in chaos when I kill the program.

Comment: @blint You don't want to take the approach you're currently doing because the socket isn't going to reach eof initially: instead the user will explicitly end the current message but leave the handle open for further communication. That's why my code explicitly checks for a line consisting of just `\r\n`. In order to fix this in your code I think you can just adapt my code to accumulate `line` values into a list and call `unlines` at the end. @blint

Comment: I suspect you may get that interleaving behaviour because of something hideous involving lazy IO but I'm not sure

Comment: I don't, indeed. After checking [the specs of HTTP](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) I eventually got why: body should be read only if a content-length is mentioned. I guess trying to read everything leaves the connection open until it times out. Thanks again, I'll make good use of your precisions!